# Add a cart link (with number of items) in the sidebar in Magento

Tags: magento, hyperlink, items, cart

I'm faced with a unique problem from a unique customer. In Magento's account screen, there are typically two places where "My Cart" makes an appearance; the top bar, and in the sidebar as a block. However, I've been tasked with removing those and placing a link (with the number of items in the cart) in the "My Account" section of the sidebar.

It appears that as a new user, I cannot post any images. This is going to pose a problem.

> MY ACCOUNT
>
> Dashboard
> Address Book
> My Cart (2 items)  <---- This link here. Within this area, and showing the number of items
> My Orders
> My Product Reviews
> May Tags
> Newsletter Subscriptions

Now, adding the link itself is problem. In fact, it's quite simple and accomplished by

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="checkout"><name>cart</name><path>checkout/cart/</path><label>My Cart</label></action>
```

within the customer.xml file.

The problem stems from listing the items in the cart within that area. If this site were only in English, a few "if" statements inside of code\core\Mage\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation.php would resolve it. However, all translation seems to be done before the addItem function is called to add those links to the menu.

I figure that if the number of items in the cart could be displayed before addItem is called, this problem would be solved, but all php from inside of the  tags gets ignored.

If anyone has a solution or any clues to this, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure we won't be able to accomplish the "My Cart (%d items)" functionality from the `addLink` block action (especially from the layout file) as we need to call `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount()` to get the number of items in our cart.

I recommend using the if statements, as you suggest, then tapping into the localisation system by using `<?php echo $this->__($str) ?>` to translate your strings in the template file, adding the translation to the locale csv files if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the link with number of items is achieved in `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links` with it's `addCartLink()` method. The user account sidebar is a `Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation` which does not have that method.  You need to add it yourself by overriding the class.

**Your/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <yourmodule>
                <class>Your_Module_Block</class>
            </yourmodule>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <account_navigation>Your_Module_Block_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Your/Module/Block/Account/Navigation.php**
<sub>(copied mostly from Mage_Checkout_Block_Links)</sub>

```
class Your_Module_Block_Account_Navigation extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Navigation
{
    public function addCartLink()
    {
        if ($parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock()) {
            $count = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getSummaryCount();

            if( $count == 1 ) {
                $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s item)', $count);
            } elseif( $count > 0 ) {
                $text = $this->__('My Cart (%s items)', $count);
            } else {
                $text = $this->__('My Cart');
            }

            $parentBlock->addLink($text, 'checkout/cart', $text, true, array(), 50, null, 'class="top-link-cart"');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**layout/customer.xml**

```
<reference name="customer_account_navigation">
    <action method="addCartLink" />
</reference>
```